# Joining 2 Data frames with OR condition

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to do the following. So I have two dataframes.

Dataset A

```
Ticker ID
XX     1
AA     NaN
NaN    2
BB     NaN
```

Dataset B

```
Tix  ID    NormDist
XX      1      .4
AA      NaN    .6
NaN     2      .9
```

I want to merge the datasets on the **Ticker** column OR the **ID** column. The output should look like the below:

```
Ticker ID     NormDist
XX     1      .4
AA     NaN    .6
NaN    2      .9
BB     NaN    NaN
```

I know I can just do two merges back to back

```
Data = pd.merge(A, B, left_on = ['ID'], right_on=['ID'], how='left')
Data = pd.merge(A, B, left_on = ['Ticker'], right_on=['Tix'], how='left')
```

But is there a smarter way of doing this? Kind of like an SQL command.

a.id = b.id **OR** a.Ticker = b.Tix

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand you can try doing a [`df.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with a inner merge:

```
df_new=(df1.combine_first(df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'Tix':'Ticker'})
                                ,on=['Ticker','ID'])))
print(df_new)

    ID  NormDist Ticker
0  1.0       0.4     XX
1  NaN       0.6     AA
2  2.0       0.9    NaN
3  NaN       NaN     BB
```